# Why does this kit only support 24V

Tags: high-voltage

However this question may seem naive, it is still something that worries me.

I bought this twilight relay kit (to turn on/off my home entrance light obviously).

Thing is: The guide shows that it can only be used with 24Volt/5A. But I (and maybe others alike) want to use it for the home power line aka 230V (110V).

As seent on the picture, on relay is written 240V/10A. So what's the problem then ?

I can guess this: 1) Manufacturer safeguard themselves. 2) the cobberlines on the print is too small to support the voltage. 3) Some other security thing is missing on this kit (like fuse or...).

Anyaway - I dont like to use this with 230V before I are certain about what could be the risk.

*note: I dont have a pic of the underside with the lines, but there is two straight 1.5mm lines from the relay to the connetion socket*

[image]

Comment: Where is the schematic?

Comment: I've added it   below

Comment: The traces on the PCB might not have proper clearance and creepage for 230V even if the relay supports it. You might consider using that relay to switch power to a second relay which might even be a HVAC contactor.

Comment: Maybe they have just given the DC specs, which are lower than the AC specs but Dan D. has a good point about clearance and creepage - you should check if they would be okay.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this board is intended to operate from a 12 Vdc power supply.  This is based both on the relay coil voltage as well as the LED series resistor.

So long as you have sufficient creepage distance from the relay terminals to any other nodes within the circuit board, you should have no problem using the relay to switch AC Mains voltages.

Comment: Creepage distance can be increased at the cost of some physical stability by cutting slots in the board at appropriate places and angles.

Comment: @Ignacio: Agree - Another factor of creepage is If the leads are too small for the load which then involve the distance. So either increase distance or add more cobber to the exsisting.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that relays have 2 ratings: First is the coil (the power necessary to activate the relay) and second the rating of the contacts (the power that can be safely switched on & off). The writing you're looking at on the relay (the 240v/10A) is the contact rating. The coil rating is 12V, and the silkscreen on the power input is also "12V". You have a 12 volt board, that can switch up to 240V, 10A. But that's the relay rating! The board may not be designed to switch that much power, and I'm betting if you tried, you'd burn up the traces. To be safe, find out the specs from the manufacturer or the source of your board. If you can't (or don't understand Chinese), then look at the distance between the traces from the relay to the connector. From having seen other similar boards, I'm thinking you're safe switching a couple of amps, but with 1.5mm traces I wouldn't go over that.

Comment: Sorry friend, i mistaken the width, is is more likely 2mm which count much in this contest. You get cudo's for noting this.

Comment: Given that for a given *power*, the **current** decreases as the voltage goes up, the trace width may in fact be insufficient for switching 24V at 10A, but certainly is plenty to switch a 250W load at 240V - the current will be 1A, instead of 10A!

Answer (score 0):

I post this as an answer (with the risk of getting a mod after me.. ;)

From other answers/comments allready posted - the problem, if such - seems to be about the isolation of the high voltage from the relay. *I had an idea about this, but i needed some comments and confirmations..and surely got that*

I recall something about the authorities and the laws about high voltage devices. There is a ocean of rules and regulations. There is ISO, EU regulations etc..

If such a kit was sold **assembled** to users as an 240V device, it should go through regulated tests, which include (as far i know), temperature (cold/hot), overvoltage, moisture, HF-noise and....and a fuse here and there..

So the producer safeguard themselves (even it is a kit) and go below the regulations. An ironic fact about this is, that You surely could start a fire with their rated 24V/5A (120W) on the kit (by shotcut).

So the simple answer must be:
This kit is not designet for high-voltage (even though it may handle this). And If You want to use it for High-V, then be d... sure to make some secure modifications.

And maybe I could add: This goes for all such home-assembly kits.

*sometimes theres no answers, only comments and assumptions: just ask about the univers and the black holes.*